# BitmapFactory.decodeStream() : IOException Resetting to invalid mark

Tags: android, bitmapfactory

I am getting Resetting to invalid mark with BitmapFactory despite the fact the Bitmap I got in return is not null and a valid Jpeg. What I am doing wrong?

Logcat:

```
01-15 18:54:42.141 12533-12533/com.example.carlo.regional2 E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
01-15 18:55:01.531 12533-12625/com.example.carlo.regional2 E/NewPostTaskFragment: Error occurred during resize: Resetting to invalid mark
01-15 18:55:01.533 12533-12533/com.example.carlo.regional2 E/NewPostActivity: Couldn't resize bitmap in background task.
```

Piece of code:

```
class LoadResizedBitmapTask extends AsyncTask<Uri, Void, Bitmap> {
    private int mMaxDimension;
public LoadResizedBitmapTask(int maxDimension) {
    mMaxDimension = maxDimension;
}

// Decode image in background.
@Override
protected Bitmap doInBackground(Uri... params) {
    Uri uri = params[0];
    //ZC

    try {
    InputStream stream = new BufferedInputStream(
            mApplicationContext.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri));
    stream.mark(stream.available());
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream);
    stream.reset();
    return bitmap;
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Can't find file to resize: " + e.getMessage());
        FirebaseCrash.report(e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error occurred during resize: " + e.getMessage());
        FirebaseCrash.report(e);
    }
```

Comment: Not all streams support `mark()` and `reset()`. I suggest that you just a fresh stream.

Comment: Thanks! That worked, you can mark it as answered!

Answer (score 4):

Java's stream APIs leave something to be desired.

In this case, `mark()` and `reset()` do not always work, particularly for streams backed by things other than simple files on the filesystem. If you want to use those, call `markSupported()` first.

The fallback is to request a fresh stream from the `ContentResolver`.